# Passing a value via props onPress

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-props

I know we can call the function like `{this.props.onPress}`, can we pass value using this callback too? Default object is passed but I want to pass a string value using this function. Is this possible, I'm posting my code to clear the situation.

```
   import Cbuttons from './../utils/CustomButtons' 
    class MainScreen extends Component {                                                 

      _onBtnClick = event => {
        console.log("Click on Button");
      }
       render() {
         return (
          <View style={customStyles.mainContainer}>
            <Cbuttons btnName="MainScreen" onPress={this._onBtnClick}/>
            <Cbuttons btnName="ScreenTwo" onPress={this._onBtnClick}/>
            <Cbuttons btnName="ScreenThree" onPress=
              {this._onBtnClick}/>
          </View>
        );   
    }
  }
   export default MainScreen;
```

while inCustom Buttons clsss

```
class MyButtons extends Component {
   constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.state={btnName:this.props.btnName};
   }
  render(){
    return(
      <TouchableOpacity  onPress={this.props.onPress} >
        <Text style={yourStyles.buttonText}> {this.props.btnName}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

export default MyButtons;
```

I want to return btnName back via this.props.onPress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problem, Thanks @mcpolo

```
class MyButtons extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <TouchableOpacity  onPress={()=>{this.props.onPress(this.props.btnName)}} >
        <Text style={yourStyles.buttonText}> {this.props.btnName}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: by calling `this.props.onPress` will pass the component itself, to pass additional information we need to turn it into function and call in the body of that function.

Comment: this.props.onPress  will not work IF YOU HAVE MULTIPLE FUNCTIONS TO CALL istead use this.props.onPress() .... thanks ... i got this idea from your answer

Answer (score 4):

```
<Cbuttons btnName="MainScreen" onPress={ () => { this._onBtnClick(this.props.btnName)}/>
```

Turn that field into a function which calls the _onBtnClick function normally with a parameter.

Then you would reflect that in the _onBtnClick() method:

```
_onBtnClick = buttonName => {
        console.log(`Click on Button ${buttonName}`);
}
```

Comment: that function to is in this.props.onPress